# How to execute mySql command in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

I have the following MySql command

```
MySqlCommand binData = new MySqlCommand("SELECT binType, binColour from bin WHERE '"
                        + sessionVarAddress +"' = address_addressID ", connect);
```

I want to try to execute this and I have tried as follows:

```
foreach(DataRow in binData.ExecuteReader())
```

but this is incorrect, how can I properly execute this command?

Comment: Why do you know this is incorrect?

Comment: `ExecuteReader` returns a *Reader*, not rows. Search for any ADO.NET tutorial that shows how the various classes are used. MySQL's Connector documentation also contains examples that show how to execute a query and read data

Comment: Visual studio debug states i need a 'type' and an 'identifier'

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, what is ADO?

Comment: @Richard1996 no, the *compiler* says the program can't be compiled because you are using the wrong classes. You can't debug this code, it doesn't even compile

Comment: @Richard1996 google it. It's the library you are trying to use. *Read* about it, don't just try random snippets to find what works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute it like:

```
var reader = binData.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
     // do whatever you need, access reader data as reader[i]
}
reader.Close();
```

See [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) for details.